# Добавление строк в команду MySQl

Tags: java, mysql

Есть команда `String sql = "insert into students(parametrs) values (parametrsUn)";`
в которую поступаю две правильно заполненные строки с параметрами и значениями, но при передаче их в подобной форме ведёт за собой выкидывание всевозможных ошибок, но если создать строку при помощи хитрости, а именно создавай строку по кусочкам, то он не позволяет это сделать.
Можно ли каким либо другим способом передать туда строку или это ошибку в других частях кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте PreparedStatement https://metanit.com/java/database/2.6.php